# Rails 4 search by 2 fields in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

how i can search by 2 field in Rails 4

I'm trying to use this commands but it all not work with me

```
@user=User.by_username_and_password(params[:username],params[:password])
session[:user_user]=@user.username
```

Also trying ton use this

```
@user=User.where(:user=>params[:username]).where(:pass=>params[:password])
session[:user_name]=@user.username
```

so how in Rails 4 i can search by 2 or 3 fields ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.find_by(username: params[:username], password: params[:password])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this way

```
User.where(username: params[:username],password: params[:password]).first
```

or

```
User.find_by(username: params[:username],password: params[:password])
```

Where **username** and **password** are the columns in your table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
 User.where("username = ? AND password = ?", params[:username], params[:password))
```